# How to get the list of installed packages vulnerable to remote attack on debian?

Tags: debian, security, apt

To track and mitigate security vulnerabilities in Debian, I am using the [`debsecan`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/debsecan) utility. The list of high rated remote code execution vulnerabilities can be found using:

```
debsecan | grep "remotely exploitable, high urgency"
```

To limit the list to vulnerabilities for which a fix is available we can use this command:

```
debsecan --suite stretch --only-fixed
```

To keep the system more secure we can upgrade the vulnerable packages and remove any unnecessary vulnerable packages (`apt list --installed | grep xx`) such as `vlc`, `thunderbird` ...

To make this task more easy for daily use when the `debsecan` database is updated and a new package is installed on my system, how can I get only the list of the **installed** packages which are vulnerable to remote attack?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`debsecan` checks installed packages by default, so all you need to do is filter its output (since it lists all the vulnerabilities affecting installed packages, which means it often lists multiple vulnerabilities per package):

```
debsecan | awk '/remotely exploitable/ { vuln[$2]++ } END { for (package in vuln) print package }' | sort
```

To get better results, you should specify the suite of course.

You can also use `debsecan-create-cron` to create a cron job which will email you a report every day.